Django with djoser and social auth not working as expected, I have problem when post my state and code on URL
`I'm using Django with Djoser to be able to use google/facebook as social authentication, I created the CustomUserModel. Im using OAuth2 for social login, I got credentials on google etc. When I GET request on this url:
enter image description here
My Redirect_url config on google console developer platform:
enter image description here
I have back the response with state and code at URL. But when I try to POST these 2 as params (state and code), I'm facing some error:
{ "non_field_errors": [ "Authentication process canceled" ] }
I'm including also the state on the cookies, because I'm using cookie HttpOnly
I tried to remake project on Google to get new credentials, but still not working. How can i solve this error? thanks guys
settings.py:
from pathlib import Path
from os import getenv, path
import os
from pathlib import Path
from django.core.management.utils import get_random_secret_key
from datetime import timedelta
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
import dotenv

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Take environment variables from .env file
dotenv_file = BASE_DIR / ".env"

SECRET_KEY = getenv("SECRET_KEY", get_random_secret_key())
API_KEY_NEWS = getenv("API_KEY_NEWS")

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = getenv("DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS")


CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [   
   ....
]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "rest_framework",
    "djoser",
    "social_django",
    "rest_framework_simplejwt",
    "django_filters",
    "corsheaders",
    "mainscreen",
    "users",
    "places",
    "news",
]


AUTH_USER_MODEL = "users.User"

# Backends
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    # For OAuth2
    "social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2",
    "social_core.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2",
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
]

# rest framework
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": ("users.authentication.CustomJWTAuthentication",),
}


SIMPLE_JWT = {
    "AUTH_HEADER_TYPES": ("Bearer", "JWT"),
    "ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME": timedelta(minutes=120),
    "REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME": timedelta(days=60),
    "SIGNING_KEY": getenv("SIGNING_KEY", get_random_secret_key()),
    "AUTH_HEADER_NAME": "HTTP_AUTHORIZATION",
    "AUTH_TOKEN_CLASSES": ("rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens.AccessToken",),
}

DJOSER = {
    "LOGIN_FIELD": "email",
    "USER_CREATE_PASSWORD_RETYPE": True,
    "USERNAME_CHANGED_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION": True,
    "PASSWORD_CHANGED_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION": True,
    "SEND_CONFIRMATION_EMAIL": True,
    "PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_URL": "password/reset/confirm/{uid}/{token}",
    "SET_PASSWORD_RETYPE": True,
    "PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_RETYPE": True,
    "USERNAME_RESET_CONFIRM_URL": "username/reset/confirm/{uid}/{token}",
    "ACTIVATION_URL": "activate/{uid}/{token}",
    "SEND_ACTIVATION_EMAIL": True,
    "SOCIAL_AUTH_TOKEN_STRATEGY": "djoser.social.token.jwt.TokenStrategy",
    "SERIALIZERS": {
        "user_create": "users.serializers.CreateUserSerializer",
        "user": "users.serializers.CreateUserSerializer",
        "user_delete": "djoser.serializers.UserDeleteSerializer",
    },
    "TOKEN_MODEL": None,
    # Change this on production
    "SOCIAL_AUTH_ALLOWED_REDIRECT_URIS": [
        "http://localhost:3000/auth/google",
        "http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook",
    ],
}


# Cookies config
AUTH_COOKIE = "access"
AUTH_COOKIE_MAX_AGE = 60 * 5  # 5 minutes
AUTH_COOKIE_REFRESH_MAX_AGE = 60 * 60 * 24  # 1 day
AUTH_COOKIE_HTTP_ONLY = True
AUTH_COOKIE_PATH = "/"
AUTH_COOKIE_SAMESITE = "None"  # For cross origin cookies


# OAuth2 Google Config
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY = getenv("SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY")
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SECRET = getenv("SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SECRET")

SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SCOPE = [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
    "openid",
]
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_EXTRA_DATA = ["first_name", "last_name"]


# middleware
MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware",
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
    "social_django.middleware.SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware",
]

ROOT_URLCONF = "core.urls"

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = "core.wsgi.application"


# Database


DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.sqlite3",
        "NAME": BASE_DIR / "db.sqlite3",
    }
}


# Password validation


AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator",
    },
]


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)


STATIC_URL = "static/"

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = "django.db.models.BigAutoField"

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"


# Email verification test
EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend"
EMAIL_HOST = getenv("EMAIL_HOST")
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_PORT = getenv("EMAIL_PORT")
EMAIL_HOST_USER = getenv("EMAIL_HOST_USER")
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = getenv("EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD")
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = env("DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL")
DOMAIN = getenv("DOMAIN")
SITE_NAME = "Findeasy"

Custom Views (to use cookies on users app):
from django.conf import settings
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from djoser.social.views import ProviderAuthView

from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import (
    TokenObtainPairView,
    TokenRefreshView,
    TokenVerifyView,
)


class CustomProviderAuthView(ProviderAuthView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)

        if response.status_code == 201:
            access_token = response.data.get("access")
            refresh_token = response.data.get("refresh")

            response.set_cookie(
                "access",
                access_token,
                max_age=settings.AUTH_COOKIE_MAX_AGE,
                path=settings.AUTH_COOKIE_PATH,
                secure=settings.AUTH_COOKIE_SECURE,
                httponly=settings.AUTH_COOKIE_HTTP_ONLY,
                samesite=settings.AUTH_COOKIE_SAMESITE,
            )
            response.set_cookie(
                "refresh",
                refresh_token,
                max_age=settings.AUTH_COOKIE_MAX_AGE,
                path=settings.AUTH_COOKIE_PATH,
                secure=settings.AUTH_COOKIE_SECURE,
                httponly=settings.AUTH_COOKIE_HTTP_ONLY,
                samesite=settings.AUTH_COOKIE_SAMESITE,
            )

        return response


class CustomTokenObtainPairView(TokenObtainPairView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)

        if response.status_code == 200:
            access_token = response.data.get("access")
            refresh_token = response.data.get("refresh")

            response.set_cookie(
                "access",
                access_token,
                max_age=settings.AUTH_COOKIE_MAX_AGE,
                path=settings.AUTH_COOKIE_PATH,
                secure=settings.AUTH_COOKIE_SECURE,
                httponly=settings.AUTH_COOKIE_HTTP_ONLY,
                samesite=settings.AUTH_COOKIE_SAMESITE,
            )
            response.set_cookie(
                "refresh",
                refresh_token,
                max_age=settings.AUTH_COOKIE_MAX_AGE,
                path=settings.AUTH_COOKIE_PATH,
                secure=settings.AUTH_COOKIE_SECURE,
                httponly=settings.AUTH_COOKIE_HTTP_ONLY,
                samesite=settings.AUTH_COOKIE_SAMESITE,
            )

        return response


class CustomTokenRefreshView(TokenRefreshView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        refresh_token = request.COOKIES.get("refresh")

        if refresh_token:
            request.data["refresh"] = refresh_token

        response = super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)

        if response.status_code == 200:
            access_token = response.data.get("access")

            response.set_cookie(
                "access",
                access_token,
                max_age=settings.AUTH_COOKIE_MAX_AGE,
                path=settings.AUTH_COOKIE_PATH,
                secure=settings.AUTH_COOKIE_SECURE,
                httponly=settings.AUTH_COOKIE_HTTP_ONLY,
                samesite=settings.AUTH_COOKIE_SAMESITE,
            )

        return response


class CustomTokenVerifyView(TokenVerifyView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        access_token = request.COOKIES.get("access")

        if access_token:
            request.data["token"] = access_token

        return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)


class LogoutView(APIView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
        response.delete_cookie("access")
        response.delete_cookie("refresh")

        return response

serializers.py:
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from djoser.serializers import UserCreateSerializer

User = get_user_model()


class CreateUserSerializer(UserCreateSerializer):
    class Meta(UserCreateSerializer.Meta):
        model = User
        fields = ['id', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password']


authentication.py (custom user auth):
from django.conf import settings
from rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication import JWTAuthentication


class CustomJWTAuthentication(JWTAuthentication):
    def authenticate(self, request):
        try:
            header = self.get_header(request)
            # Try first send cookie, if theres no cookie, get from header.
            if header is None:
                raw_token = request.COOKIES.get(settings.AUTH_COOKIE)
            else:
                raw_token = self.get_raw_token(header)

            if raw_token is None:
                return None

            validated_token = self.get_validated_token(raw_token)

            return self.get_user(validated_token), validated_token
        except:
            return None


